# Magento 2: How to display author's name outside the admin grid

Tags: magento2, module, admin, grid, blog

I just have learned magento 2.[image][image]
I have a table ecommage_blog in which there is an author_id attribute (which is the id of the customer that created that blog), so how can I display the author's name of that blog on the admin grid?
thank you very much?

Answer (score 0):

```
class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PurchasedPrice"
```

like this, you have to add in column tag. Something like this

```
<column name="grand_total" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PurchasedPrice">
```

for other parts take reference

https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/module-sales/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PurchasedPrice.php

Basically, you need to add class specify from where to take value to display in the grid and then you need to create the class for value manipulation